# Showing multiple burials in same grave for Cemetery GIS?

Tags: polygon, spatial-database, relates

I am an intern creating a Geodatabase for a municipal cemetery.

The one lot can hold up to 3 people (2 people, 1 cremation)  two people at the most.

How would I show that information on the map using a polygon while including the position of each body?

The lots are a fixed size. I am using ArcMap 10.2.2

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  There have been a number of earlier [Q&As about Cemetery GIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=cemetery+is%3Aquestion) asked here, and so I think you should review them, to ensure that any questions you ask have not already been covered.  I suspect your challenge will be how to deal with the one-to-many relationship between grave sites and the people buried in them, both for your data modelling and later display.  Can you **edit** your question to include the GIS software that you are using, please?

Comment: Hash patterns work for me. Lowest at 45 degrees, mid at 90 and top at 135. Don't make the lines too thick or dark as you will need to discern each. What software are you trying to do this in? Do you need each person to be a different symbol in the legend? Perhaps something like annotating/labeling the plots might be the best, but you will need to keep an attribute for lowest/middle/top in each plot.

Answer (score 3):

Use a colour scale, getting darker for each additional person buried in a plot. [ColorBrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/) is a great place to look for good colour schemes. I imagine most would just be one person, but ones that are darker indicate the presence of multiple people.

If your problem is how you associate cemetary plots and a table of people buried therein, then you need to read about one-to-many relationships.